# Indirect formula to add table field to vlookup formula

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, vlookup

So I have to get a price based 3 variables
Diamond size
Diamond quality
Diamond Shape

So I made tables depending on shapes

This formula is working
Diamond size = `H11`  = 1
Diamond quality = `$K$3` =3
Diamond Shape = `'DIAMOND PRICES '!$A$64:$F$103`

`=VLOOKUP(H11,'DIAMOND PRICES '!$A$64:$F$103,$K$3,FALSE)`  = correct answer 600

So Move on to add the diamond table variable 
I get the answer 
`G11` = `'DIAMOND PRICES '!$A$64:$F$103`

`=VLOOKUP(H11,(indirect(G11)),$K$3,FALSE)` - #REF!
Reads it correctly but I get this message :

> Function `INDIRECT` parameter 1 value is `'DIAMOND PRICES  '!$A$64:$F$103'`. It is not a valid cell/range reference.

The only difference I can see is the `'` at the end so not sure why it is there, or **why the formula is not working or reading the formula correctly**.

Comment: Welcome. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: You need to change the permissions of your sheet. At the moment it is private.

Comment: @MarkPoter try remove the single quotes who surround `DIAMOND PRICES`

Comment: @MarkPoter You should be aware that by choosing to share your spreadsheet, your email address will be unavoidably exposed.

Comment: @pjmg - Thank you, your answer worked

Comment: @tedinoz - Thank you I was not aware of that

Comment: @MarkPoter no problem, don't forget to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quotes around `DIAMOND PRICES`.

Comment: [This comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/141223/indirect-formula-to-add-table-field-to-vlookup-formula/141256#comment128697_141223) on question is the answer of the question. I have added same to the answer.